# Rxjs: Create Observable that is a delayed offset of another observable

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming

Is there an easy way to create an observable that is an offset of another?

For example, let's say Observable1 emits [1,2,3,4,5].

How would I create Observable2 from Observable1 such that Observable2 emits [1,2,3,4]  (so, it emits nothing when Observable1 emits 1, it emits 1 when Observable1 emits 2, etc.)

> Obs1 Start
>   -------1--------2----------3------------4-------------5----------------->
>
> Obs2 Start
>   -----------------1----------2------------3-------------4----------------->

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify. Should the resulting observable emit the latest value from Obs1 whenever Obs2 emits anything? Or does the value emitted by Obs2 mean something, and if so what? What is the desired behavior if Obs2 emits `[4, 3, 2, 1]`?

Comment: I'm not trying to create a third observable based on Obs1 and Obs2. 

Rather, I'm trying to create Obs2 FROM Obs1, such that Obs2 is always "one value behind" Obs1.

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`bufferCount`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-bufferCount) and [`map`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-map) operators to do what you want:

```js
const source = new Rx.Subject();
const offset = source.bufferCount(2, 1).map(values => values[0]);

source.subscribe(value => console.log(`source = ${value}`));
offset.subscribe(value => console.log(`offset = ${value}`));

source.next(1);
source.next(2);
source.next(3);
source.next(4);
source.next(5);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

`bufferCount(2, 1)` will emit a two-value buffer each time a value is received - once there are two values in the buffer, that is. So the first value in the buffer will be offset by one source emission.

You could substitute `bufferCount(2, 1)` with [`pairwise()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-pairwise) which does the same thing.

Comment: Ah!  I did not realize there was a second argument for BufferCount that let's you specify an overlapping buffer.

Thank you!

Comment: Updated the answer to mention `pairwise` - which I'd forgotten about.